# Gearman client doBackground always returns GEARMAN_TIMEOUT

Tags: php, gearman

So, ive got a simple gearman system running right now, with a worker running.

The worker basically just takes the payload (a random number in this case, and is supposed to echo it back to the screen. Literally an `echo`, not returning to the client.

The client sends the random number. Im trying to do a `$client->doBackground( 'post', 65482, md5(uniqid()));` but its coming back with a 47 error (`GEARMAN_TIMEOUT`) every time.

`getErrNo()` returns 0, `error()` returns something about `GEARMAN_TIMEOUT`

However, when i change it to just `$client->do(blah, blah, blah)`, it works just fine.

I've even occasionally seen it where the worker still echo's the number, even after getting the timeout error...

```
public function execute()
    {
        $method = 'do';
        if( !$this->getBlock() )
        {
            $method .= ( $this->getPriority() == 'Normal' ? '' : $this->getPriority() ) . 'Background';
        }
        else
        {
            $method .= $this->getPriority();
        }
        echo "Method: $method \t Worker: {$this->getName()} \t Payload: {$this->getPayload()} \t Hash: {$this->getHash()}\n";
        $this->setResult(
            $this->getClient()
                ->$method(
                    $this->getName(),
                    $this->getPayload(),
                    $this->getHash()
                )
        );
        if( $this->getClient()->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS )
        {
            echo "Code: " . $this->getClient()->returnCode() . "\t" . GEARMAN_TIMEOUT . "\n";
        }
    }
```

that echo comes back with

`Method: doHighBackground    Worker: leadposter      Payload: 10930      Hash: 091878f5965e4a1de2992c607b3c562b240792a6`

Heres the error info

```
["error":"Uecode\GearmanBundle\Gearman\Job":private]=>
  array(4) {
    ["attempts"]=>
    int(3)
    ["return_code"]=>
    int(47)
    ["error_no"]=>
    int(0)
    ["error"]=>
    string(103) "gearman_wait(GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) timeout reached, no servers were available -> libgearman/universal.cc:325"
  }
```

Comment: If you are running multiple servers, make sure both can ping the server with the gearman instance.

Comment: just one server at the moment

Comment: Can you post the contents of the echo line; `echo "Method: $method \t Worker: {$this->getName()} \t Payload: {$this->getPayload()} \t Hash: {$this->getHash()}\n";` ?

Comment: Try wrapping the `$method` var in braces; `$this->getClient()->{$method}(`

Comment: Check out this post and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076200/gearman-with-multiple-servers-and-php-workers

Comment: yeah, that doesnt really help. Only running on one server, and not shutting it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Connections werent persisting across methods... so, build a server pool, and connected to the servers just before running the job

Answer (score 0):

If your `gearmand` is on another port, be sure `AddServers` knows, else will `GEARMAN_TIMEOUT`.

`gearmand -d -p 4769`

`$worker->addServers(127.0.0.1:4769);`